# Downloaded attachment doesn't show correct extension name

Tags: java, postgresql, struts2, download, attachment

I am using postgresql as backend. I have saved attachments & attachment title in case_attachments table.
When I click to download attachments, it does download it. But the attachment name comes as this
**downloadAttachFile** and the type as **action** . I would be saving attachments of multiple types such as jpg, pdf, doc etc. So while downloading it is important that the filename & extension is correct.

This is my struts.xml

```
        <action name="downloadAttachFile" class="abc.actions.mypackage" method="downloadAttachFile">
        <result name="success" type="stream">
        <param name="contentType">application/octet-stream/text/plain/doc</param>
        <param name="inputName">fileInputStream</param>
        <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename=%{AttachFileName}</param>
        <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>           
        </result>               
    </action>
```

And action method

```
    public String downloadAttachFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
    String AttachFileName = ServletActionContext.getRequest().getParameter("myFileFileName");
    fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(AttachFileName));
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

When I right click and open it using the correct tool it opens correctly. So only problem here is the name & extension type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear why, if you are retrieving it from the database, you are reading it from the request... btw:

1. Your action property must be private, at class level (and not declared at method level as you did), with a getter, and starting with a lowercase character to follow conventions:

   ```
   private String attachFileName;

   public String getAttachFileName(){
       return attachFileName;
   }

   public String downloadAttachFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
       attachFileName = ServletActionContext.getRequest().getParameter("myFileFileName");
       fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(AttachFileName));
       return SUCCESS;
   }
   ```
2. You need to store, retrieve and set the real, correct `contentType`. This:

   ```xml
   <param name="contentType">application/octet-stream/text/plain/doc</param>
   ```

   is a monster that may turn your browser into a nightmare generator.

Comment: i changed the content type :
 <param name="contentType">application/octet-stream</param>
and rest as u said. It is working perfectly awesome. Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome. Your contentType is working because you are downloading it as `attachment`, it wouldn't work correctly if trying to open it inside the browser with `inline` (although `application/octet-stream` is the right contentType to use if the source is unknown...). Consider storing the right contentType when saving the file, or the first time you'll try displaying the file in the browser you will have problems with many Mime Types.

Comment: I will surely make a note about it. Thanks again for the help.